# remove($object) is not deleted from DB

Tags: typo3, extbase

remove() does not delete record from MySQl

Controller:

```
    $roomsRejected = $this->roomsRepository->findByIdAccepted($roomIDRejected); 
foreach ($roomsRejected as $rooms){
    $this->roomsRepository->remove($rooms);
   }
```

When I remove($rooms) from repository, it is not getting deleted from the database. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository just marks entities for removal and during shut down, the persistence manager will purge any entities marked for deletion.

However if you choose to exit early, then you'll have to inject the persistence manager and call persistAll() yourself.